# How do I get CLI curl to run on debian lenny

Tags: curl, debian

I have a machine running debian lenny.
I need to be able to use curl from the command line but it is just not available.
When trying to use it I get:

```
curl: command not found
```

What exactly do I need to install to have this command available ?

UPDATE:

I tried to run `apt-get install curl`
and got the following:

```
xxxxx:~# apt-get install curl

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lockfile-progs liblockfile1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates libcurl3 libldap-2.4-2 libssh2-1 openssl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates curl libcurl3 libldap-2.4-2 libssh2-1 openssl
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1877kB of archives.
After this operation, 4583kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main libldap-2.4-2 2.4.11-1+lenny1
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
Err http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main libcurl3 7.18.2-8lenny4
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
Err http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main curl 7.18.2-8lenny4
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
Err http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny/main openssl 0.9.8g-15+lenny6
  404 Not Found
Get:1 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny/main ca-certificates 20080809 [151kB]
Err http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main openssl 0.9.8g-15+lenny6
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
Get:2 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny/main libssh2-1 0.18-1 [64.3kB]
Fetched 215kB in 0s (391kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.11-1+lenny1_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/openssl_0.9.8g-15+lenny6_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/c/curl/libcurl3_7.18.2-8lenny4_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/c/curl/curl_7.18.2-8lenny4_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.36 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
xxxxx:~#
```

so I tried

```
xxxxx:~# apt-get update
Get:1 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny Release.gpg [1034B]
Get:2 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny Release [85.6kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org stable/updates Release.gpg [836B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org stable/updates Release [86.9kB]
Ign http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny Release
Get:5 http://ftp.debian.org unstable Release.gpg [836B]
Ign http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny/contrib Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.debian.org stable/updates Release
Get:6 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny/main Packages [6873kB]
Get:7 http://ftp.debian.org unstable Release [188kB]
Ign http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.debian.org stable/updates/contrib Packages/DiffIndex
Get:8 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main Packages [236kB]
Get:9 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/contrib Packages [622B]
Ign http://ftp.debian.org unstable Release
Get:10 http://ftp.debian.org unstable/non-free Packages/DiffIndex [2023B]
Get:11 http://ftp.debian.org unstable/non-free Sources/DiffIndex [2023B]
Get:12 http://ftp.debian.org unstable/non-free Packages [150kB]
Get:13 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny/contrib Packages [94.3kB]
Get:14 http://ftp.debian.org unstable/non-free Sources [121kB]
Fetched 7842kB in 3s (2421kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu lenny Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org stable/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org unstable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

and then

```
xxxxx:~# apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  curl: Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

followed by:

```
xxxxx:~# apt-get remove curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package curl is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lockfile-progs liblockfile1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
```

and

```
xxxxx:~# apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  curl: Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I must be missing something important here...

YET ANOTHER UPDATE:

here is what it says when running apt-get install libcurl3

```
xxxxx:~# apt-get install libcurl3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libcurl3: Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.7+dfsg) but it is not installable
            Depends: libidn11 (>= 1.13) but 1.8+20080606-1 is to be installed
            Depends: libssh2-1 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

sources.list files has the following:

```
# the main Debian packages.
deb http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/debian/debian/ lenny main contrib
# Uncomment the deb-src line if you want 'apt-get source'
# to work with most packages.
# deb-src http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/debian/debian/ lenny main contrib
# uncommenting the following line will enable security updates
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib

# for sun-java5 packages in unstable
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ unstable non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ unstable non-free
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install it through aptitude:

`sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: What does it says when running `apt-get install libcurl3`?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your package sources (take a look at your last output: _[...] if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming [...]_). I would try to update them again (`apt-get update`) and look for errors. You can also try to generate a new `sources.list` (http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/) for your distribution, update the sources and install again. Hope it helps.

Comment: I already did an `apt-get update` - look at the second gray block in the comment. it seems to have some PGP issues near the end, any idea what do those mean ?

Comment: I guess the PGP warnings are not directly related with your problem. You can read more about it in http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_apt_uses_Release.gpg. Could you post your `sources.list` file?

Comment: added contents of sources.list

Comment: finally. using `aptitude install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring` fixed the broken/missing keys I had and now everything works as expected, including curl.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your sources.list, for example, (deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian wheezy contrib main non-free), then try to update your package sources (`apt-get update`),(`apt-get upgrade`) to upgrade your debian. After that, re-install your curl (`apt-get install curl`).

Comment: you do realize that this was answered almost 7 years ago ?

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu/debian use: `apt-get update -y && apt-get install curl -y`

centos use: `yum update -y && yum install curl -y`

from: https://233v2.com/post/1/